# Set opportunity amount filed value as default value in related object field

Tags: salesforce

I have a custom object **FlightRequest** for **Opportunity** object and there is an **Amount** filed both in **opportunity** and **FlightRequest**.

I want to set **Opportunity**'s **Amount** filed value as default in **FlightRequest**'s **Amount** Field. So whenever **New Button** clicked for **FlightRequest**, **Amount** input should already field with **Opportunity**'s **Amount**

I m using **Standard page layout** not any visual force page layout and can not use it.

I saw there is an option to set default value for a field but Opportunity object is not shown in **Select Field Type** options

please advice how can i accomplish this

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with a "unofficially" supported technique (meaning everyone has been doing it for 10 yrs and while they say it's unsupported they'll never break it, too many customers use it) called URL hacking.  Basically when they click the new button you'll pass the value for your field into the new record page dynamically based on the parent record.  There is a good [blog post tutorial](http://www.interactiveties.com/b_pass_vars_url.php) on this.  Give it a try and that should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a Master-Detail relationship between the objects, then you can setup the Amount field on the FlightRequest object as a formula field that references the Amount field on the Opportunity.

This should accomplish what you need to do.  The Master-Detail relationship is essential for the cross-object reference of fields.

Comment: i can't use formula as filed need to be editable as well also want to show default value when "New" button is clicked to add new record before adding new record, hope you get my point